# LibGdx [FATAL EXCEPTION] Loading a skin .json file

Tags: java, android, json, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm using Intellij. Everything was working fine, and the APK is deployed in my Android but it just stays black screen and return to home saying that "'the game' stopped:

```
    1023-1051/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1591
Process: net.mygdx.game.android, PID: 1023
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ax: Error reading file: jsonSkin.json
        at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.mygdx.game.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ax: Error reading file: skins/jsonSkin.json
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.mygdx.gam.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ax:
        at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at net.mygdx.game.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.b.e: Class not found: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at net.mygdx.game.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at net.mygdx.game.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.mygdx.gam.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.mygdx.gam.android-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.mygdx.gam.android-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.k.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.j.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.k.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.e.a.a.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at org.mygdx.gam.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.i.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

This on is my .json file;

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
    white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
    red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
    black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
    dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
    default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
    default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
    dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
    default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
    default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
    default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle: {
    default: {
        label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
        background: default-pane, wrapWidth: 150
    }
},
}
```

And these lines are the ones who are weird because if I get rid of them the program works just fine except from the button that Obviously doesn't appear;

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("jsonSkin.json"));
TextButton btnStart = new TextButton("Start!!", skin);
btnStart.setPosition(50f,400f);
btnStart.setSize(260f,60f);
mainMenu.addActor(btnStart);
```

Comment: It looks like your Proguard config is not excepting libgdx classes. Since Skin loads classes by reflection, you must not allow Proguard to change the names of those classes.

Comment: You sure this exists? `skins/jsonSkin.json`

Comment: Menno Gouw -- I may had changed something when posting here but i can asure you that i put a jsonSkin.json in SKIN/ folder and assets too.

Comment: Please `_-Tenfour-_` Can you tell me more about how can i not Allow proguard to change names ?? –

Comment: I Diabled Proguard but there is still an error please can someone help ????

Answer (score 9):

Put this in your config:

```
 -keep class com.badlogic.**{
   **[] $VALUES;
    *;
}
```

It'll fix this issue, and issues with reflection.

### EDIT :

Above is the top level rule that disables all of `ProGuard’s` goodness on particular package. No shrinking, no obfuscation; not for classes, not for members.

`Proguard` obfuscate classes that we're using in our skin file, `Skin` loads classes by reflection, so we must **not allow** `Proguard` to change the names of those classes.

1. double-asterisk in the package means every class under every package under that top-level package;
2. asterisk inside the curly braces applies to every member (variables, methods, and constants) inside those class.

Comment: So what is this line actually doing? I'm very new to proguard and this looks like a huge wildcard for pretty much everything. In that case Proguard is only usefull for obfuscating and not so much for minifying and reducing file size. I +1, but it would be nice if you elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Madmenyo I added some more detail, above rule disable proguard on libgdx package but still your own classes is safe(obfuscated) by proguard. If you're more concerned about obfuscation, you can go deeper and disable  obfuscation on `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui` and add some external classes like `BitmapFont` or `Color` that may be you've in skin file.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is json serializer needs exact field name to do its job.

Abhishek is correct but I just need to ignore shrinking only for scene2d package, so I put this on **proguard-rules.pro** file

```
 -keep class com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.**{
    **[] $VALUES;
     *;
 }
```

It will optimize all the other code except for skin loader and its components.

Also you need to put something similar if you are doing json de/serializing with your own classes.

```
 -keep class com.your.game.data.**{
    **[] $VALUES;
     *;
 }
```

Here is a screenshot to find the **proguard-rules.pro** file on Android Studio for beginners 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your **proguard rules**

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont

Answer (score 0):

In my case in `build.gradle` i had this config for release build:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      debuggable true
    }
```

But my `proguard-rules.pro` file was missing - the default is now `proguard-project.txt` instead. So I changed config to this:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
      debuggable true
    }
```

And then applied proper proguard rules as in previous answers.